# Rails form select for join table produces ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, select, multi-select

I am trying to setup the data input for a database which contains for example projects. Projects can be part of a series, have multiple curators, etc.

I either get the series form displayed with:

```
<%= f.collection_select :series, Series.order('word asc'), :id, :word, {}, {:class => 'select-field-style'} %>
```

with proper styling, but upon submit I get

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::ProjectsController#update
Series(#2212122800) expected, got String(#2183812080)
```

with

```
<%= f.select :series, Series.all.collect{ |p| [ p.word, p.id ]}, :include_blank => true, :class => "select-field-style" %>
```

CSS is not applied, but I manage to get a blank option.
Submit produces the same response.

For the curators

```
<%= f.select :curators, options_for_select(Author.all.map{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, f.object.curators), {}, {:class => "form-control selectpicker", :include_blank => true, :multiple => true} %>
```

produces a multi select field with my custom styling and on submit I get a similar error

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::ProjectsController#update
Author(#2214244880) expected, got String(#2183812080)
```

I need to be able to apply my own **CSS** to the selector, have the ability for **single**, **multiple** and **blank**. The forms do not work and no version permits all options.

These relations are established through join-tables. My models are:

**Project Model**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :series, :curators

# Associations 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :curators, :class_name => "Author", :join_table => "projects_curators"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :series, :join_table => "projects_series" 
end
```

**Series Model**

```
class Series < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :word

# Associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, :join_table => "projects_series"
```

end

**Curator join table**

```
class ProjectsCurator < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :project_id, :author_id

# Associations
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :author
end
```

**Author model**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

# Associations
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects, :join_table => "projects_curators"
end
```

## Update

Thanks to @xploshioOn's answer I am now able to get the proper selection options right.

```
<%= f.select(:series, Series.order('word asc').map{|s| [s.word, s.id]}, {:include_blank => false}, {:class => 'select-field-style'}) %>
```

Renders a selection menu with custom CSS.

```
<%= f.select(:curators, Author.order('name asc').map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => "select-field-style", :multiple => true}) %>
```

Renders a selection menu with custom CSS, multiple selection option and blank.

Unfortunately on submit I still get the:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::ProjectsController#update
Series(#2285826200) expected, got String(#2257413120)
```

and

```
Author(#2286926340) expected, got String(#2257413120)
```

Strangely:

```
<%= f.select(:curators, Author.order('name asc').map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => "select-field-style", :multiple => true}) %>
```

has the expected outcome, while

```
<%= f.select(:curators, Author.order('name asc').map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}, {:include_blank => true, :multiple => true}, {:class => "select-field-style"}) %>
```

Why? And how can I get the submit to work?

## Update 2

The form for series and most other forms are now working as intended. The forms which are related to habtm relations through join tables and class names do not work yet.

Some context: In these cases I need to relate projects to organizers, curators, supporters, etc. The relations are between the following models:

Project.rb - projects_curator.rb - author.rb

Project.rb - projects_supporter.rb - institution.rb

In both cases I have different versions of the join-table and each time I have the class/alias declared in the author and institution model. Just as written previously.

With the select form mentioned above I get the following error upon submit

```
Started PUT "/admin/projects/1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Dec 05 20:03:31 +0100 2018
Processing by Admin::ProjectsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"project"=>{"place"=>"Moon", "hero_id"=>"1", "name"=>"Rocket", "year"=>"1492", "description"=>"And now the news.", "curators"=>["", "14"], "category_id"=>"2", "project_id"=>"1", "series_ids"=>["", "3"]}, "utf8"=>"✓", "commit"=>"Save", "authenticity_token"=>"some_token", "id"=>"1"}
  Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Author(#2302596480) expected, got String(#2274315260)):
  app/controllers/admin/projects_controller.rb:28:in `update'


  Rendered /Users/account/.rvm/gems/ruby-version@app/gems/actionpack-x.x.x/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/account/.rvm/gems/ruby-version@app/gems/actionpack-x.x.x/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/account/.rvm/gems/ruby-version@app/gems/actionpack-x.x.x/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (8.3ms)
```

The last part of the trace is:

```
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:204:in `raise_on_type_mismatch'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:318:in `replace'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:318:in `each'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:318:in `replace'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:41:in `writer'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:51:in `curators='
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `send'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:85:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `each'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:78:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:212:in `update_attributes'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (x.x.x) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:211:in `update_attributes'
app/controllers/admin/projects_controller.rb:28:in `update'
actionpack (x.x.x) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (x.x.x) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (x.x.x) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
```

The relative action from the projects_controller is standard:

```
def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      flash[:notice] = 'project was successfully updated.'
      redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @project
    else
      @page_title = 'Edit project'
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution for the mismatch also thanks to xploshioOn's answer.

I had to use the plural form of the id in all form select fields such as:

series_ids, curator_ids.

My final line of script is therefore:

```
<%= f.select(:curator_ids, Curator.order('name asc').map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select-field-style'})  %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the class and the include blank on a select, like this

```
<%= f.select(:series, Series.order('word asc').map{|s| [s.word, s.id]}, {:include_blank => true}, {:class => 'select-field-style'})  %>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your input. With your suggestion I am able to get all the options right, but still trigger the 'AssociationTypeMismatch in Admin::ProjectsController#update'. I will update my question with the necessary info.

Comment: Can you add the code of that action to the question and the complete error?

Comment: I have added some more details. I am looking at the fact that I used different join table to connect two models in different ways. Tomorrow I will try to go from habtm and join-table to has many though a third model. I will report back, but any hint is appreciated very much. As a matter of fact in the remaining forms, which are all habtm, the form does not highlight the existing datasets in the select form, as it now does for series.